# Getting count of distinct column value grouped to another column

Tags: t-sql, group-by, count, max, dense-rank

My select below gives the following result

```
SELECT 
    Fruit
  , Lot
  , rank() over (partition by Fruit ORDER BY Lot) as [Rank]
FROM Fruit_Basket
```

| Fruit | Lot | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | 1140 | 1 |
| Banana | 1150 | 2 |
| Apple | 2630 | 1 |
| Melon | 1140 | 1 |
| Melon | 1140 | 1 |

Is there any way of getting a MAX(Rank() over...) or something similar?
I want to know the max count distinct of lots per fruit. Like below:

| Count | MultipleLots |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

I want to do this without having to make another select or join.
I've been trying stuff like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Distinct Fruit) <-- Works of course
  , COUNT(DISTINCT Lot) OVER (Partition by Fruit) <-- Many Errors, due to no group by and distinct
  , MAX(rank() over (partition by Fruit ORDER BY Lot)) <-- Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate
FROM Fruit_Basket
```

The only way I manage to get my result is using a Cross apply, forcing me to make another database search through the same table, which I'd prefer not to.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Distinct Fruit)
  , MAX(lots)
FROM Fruit_Basket f
CROSS APPLY(SELECT COUNT(Distinct Lot) as Lots
  FROM Fruit_Basket fi
  WHERE fi.Fruit = f.Fruit
) CA
```

Comment: Why does it matter if you read the table twice? Are you experiencing performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a large dataset to test with, but I think this should perform reasonably well and only access your table once.

```
WITH cte_DistinctLot AS (
    SELECT Fruit
        ,LotCnt = COUNT(DISTINCT LOT)
    FROM Fruit_Basket
    GROUP BY Fruit
)

SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*)
    ,MaxLotCnt = MAX(LotCnt)
FROM cte_DistinctLot
```